# Angular JS + $http post does not actually post the data

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I have created one function in Angular JS which will make AJAX call. I am facing problem that I can not get data in $_POST though it shows me in JSON object when check in browser's console.

```
$scope.checkLogin = function(){
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('user_email', $scope.user_email);
    data.append('user_password', $scope.user_password);

    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: siteUrl+'/api/login.php',
        data: data,
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log("Success! " + response);
        $scope.login = response.data; 
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("Failure! " + response);      
    });
};
```

can anyone please advice what to do if I want to get data in $_POST?

Comment: what are you seeing in the console? make sure you are injecting the http service in your controller

Comment: @WildWidow: Yes, I have added $http service in my controller. I see request data passed in JSON format.

Comment: try adding `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}' inside your http request

Comment: Share more code to debug it;

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.stringify` to convert your object into post data

So your line

```
data: data,
```

becomes

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```